# Is there a way to shift up the y-axis in matplotplib so that zero starts from "higher up"?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I have a problem regarding the starting point of y-axis. My data has some values that are almost below zero, but I dont want my graph to show negative values. I want my y-axis values to start from zero. Can I shift up the y-axis, still starting from zero?

Here is the current graph with plt.ylim(0, 1750):

[image: current graph]

And here it is without manually setting plt.ylim():

[image: no ylim]

Here is the desired outcome:

[image: desired]

Comment: As you can see in the first graph, when the zero from y-axis is at the same level as the zero from x-axis, all the observed points are not showing in the graph.

Comment: Have you tried setting your ylim to a slightly negative start point? Something like (-10, 1750)?

Comment: Wow that worked! Thank you so much Michael S. Im little bit confused tho. I set plt.ylim(-30, 1750). Now it is showing as like in the desired outcome, and zero is still the lowest number showing on y-axis. So by default the lowest point is always zero no matter what we specify to the plt.ylim()?

Comment: No, it's just that your y-tick range is in intervals of 500. So, as long as you don't set the bottom limit to something close to that, it won't show the -500. I'll place this as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place the `ylim` as slightly negative to "shift" your yaxis down slightly below zero. So long as you set a negative bottom ylim that is not as much as the intervals of you yticks, it shouldn't populate a negative ytick on your graph,

With a slightly smaller bottom limit:

```py
x = np.arange(0,1000)
y = np.arange(0,1000)

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.ylim(-50)
```

[image]

With a bottom ylim that equals the ytick interval:

```py
x = np.arange(0,1000)
y = np.arange(0,1000)

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.ylim(-200)
```

[image]